# Running an IRC bot on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, coffeescript

I've got my bot up and running, and I would like it to run on Heroku to keep it persistently connected to our IRC-channel. This is the content of my procfile:

```
web: coffee marvin.coffee
```

(The bot's name is marvin).

And this is `marvin.coffee`

```
irc = require 'irc'
config = require('./config').config

client = new irc.Client(config.server, config.nick, config.options)

# IRC-listeners
```

I'm never creating any HTTP server, and I was hoping that it was possible to simply run this coffeescript on Heroku in order for my bot to run, but I get the following error:

```
 Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

The bot is launched, and joins the channel, but immediately leaves due to the fact that Heroku kills the process due to this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it work if you change `web: coffee marvin.coffee` to `bot: coffee marvin.coffee` in your `Procfile`?

Comment: fyi: the proper name is `worker` but the doc say only web is special, the other process types can be named arbitrarily. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Comment: Yeah, so there is no "proper" name unless you want web processes ;)